# Backspace key not working in Google apps script editor

Tags: google-apps-script, google-apps-script-editor

**The Problem:**

I'm writing a script in the Google apps script editor.  If I type something on a line let's call that line 'line 1' (not the first line of the script document) and then press enter to drop to 'line 2' I can no longer press backspace to go back up to the end of line 1.

If I move the cursor back up to the end of line 1, by either clicking there or using the arrow keys, I can't use the backspace key to clear any of the text.  However, if I put the cursor in front of any of the characters on line 1 I can use the delete button to delete them no problem.  Interestingly enough ctrl + backspace does delete the word to the left of the cursor.

**Here's what I've found/tried:**

**tried with:**

1. scroll lock on/off
2. insert on/off

**Results:**

- arrow keys work fine
- shift + arrow keys work fine (selecting text)
- arrow keys work (navigating)
- delete key works
- home/end keys work

> I've tried backspace in multiple tabs i.e. in docs, the omnibox (and here) and it works fine in all of these instances except in the apps script editor.

I've CTRL + F5'ed the editor tab, the document tab (which closes the editor tab), reopened the editor tab, closed and reopened chrome all for good measure but to no avail.

> I don't have any extensions that mess with the backspace key but I checked the keyboard shortcuts section to double verify that nothing is mapped to the backspace key and then **finally just disabled all extensions...still doesn't work**.

Please help.

Comment: You can search the issue tracker [Link to Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open)  If you can describe the exact situation that can reproduce the problem, then the Apps Script developers might be able to do something.  What operating system are you using?  What browser and version?  Does this happen in every Apps Script project?

Comment: Windows 10, Chrome Version 62.0.3202.75 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Yep, every project :/

Comment: well darn...OK I found the problem.  I had installed Google Input Tools...which is an extension (I thought I had disabled all of them).  Anyway, when I disabled that extension specifically backspace started working again just fine.  It just seems strange that Google Input Tools literally only affected that one page 'type'.

this.getEffect() != logical oh well.  I hope this helps someone someday!

Answer (score 2):

well darn...OK I found the problem. I had installed Google Input Tools...which is an extension (I thought I had disabled all of them). Anyway, when I disabled that extension specifically backspace started working again just fine. It just seems strange that Google Input Tools literally only affected that one page 'type'. this.getEffect() != logical oh well. I hope this helps someone someday!

Comment: Thanks for answering your own question.  Perhaps it will help someone else in the future.